# Restricting users to access C drive in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, hard-drive

i have a winform to merge few file and save the merge files in a Directory.

The directory in which it is saved ,it deletes the whole files and subdirectory in it .

Now i want that the user should not be able to save the file in My Computer,C,D Drives.

User can choose the directory through FolderBrowserDialog.

How can i restrict the user in doing so?
Can u plz help out?

Comment: why don't you instead restrict the user by not allowing him to browse and store your files always in the same place? that way you will not have the headache of anticipating everywhere the user may save it.

Comment: you could then just check if something is there already and in that case prompt for action (e.g. merge or delete previous contents), just a thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you mean that the user chooses the directory using the `FolderBrowserDialog` ? In any case, neither the `FolderBrowserDialog` nor the `SaveFileDialog` offer any in-built means of restricting the user selection.

Your most straightforward option therefore is to validate the user's selection and check if it is not one of directories you have chosen to restrict access to. You could also set code permissions and disallow permission for your code to save files into the restricted folders.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way of doing it would be use the access rights in Windows NTFS file system.

Comment: http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Understanding-Windows-NTFS-Permissions.html